# Regex -- replace all spaces before a particular character

Tags: regex, intellij-idea

The goal is to make something like

```
This is some text=This is some text
```

become:

```
This\ is\ some\ text=This is some text
```

I've been playing with variations of things I know will grab spaces/whitespaces (like "\ " or \s) in front of (?==) which seems to select until the = character, but nothing seems to be working in Intellij IDEA's search and replace.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't have IntelliJ to test, but this - `(\s)(?=.*=)` should work. Replace it with `\$1`

Comment: That worked, though I used a literal space instead of the \s because it was picking up some additional white space I didn't want replaced. Also had to do some silly escaping for the replace (\\\\$1
)

Thanks!

Comment: Oh! I'll add that as answer, so that you can accept.

Comment: @RohitJain - Just a reminder, could you add the answer? Otherwise this question remains in the "Unanswered" list. (See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90263/unanswered-question-answered-in-comments for elaboration of why this is helpful.) Thanks!

Comment: @RohitJain - If you're game to recap the solution as your own answer, I'll delete my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Copying the answer from the comments in order to remove this question from the "Unanswered" filter:

> This - `(\s)(?=.*=)` should work. Replace it with `\$1`

~ answer per [Rohit Jain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1679863/rohit-jain)

This was additionally confirmed by the OP:

> That worked, though I used a literal space instead of the \s because it was picking up some additional white space I didn't want replaced. Also had to do some silly escaping for the replace (\\$1 )